# Where can I get fundamental data on US public stocks in original form?

Tags: equities, data, fundamentals, data-source

I'm looking for fundamental data on US public companies. If anyone could recommend paid or free sources of the fundamentals in ***original, non-standardized*** form that would be great. I tried scraping the XBRL files from the SEC but its way too complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by non-standardized, but probably Compustat may be what you are looking for. If you have any connection to a university, almost all universities will have access to WRDS which will give you access to Compustat.

Answer (score 0):

I use EODHistorical for fundamentals. The API is simple to plug in.

https://eodhistoricaldata.com